# Forget to add a guest in non-free cancellation booking in booking.com

Tags: hotels, booking.com

A friend of mine that lives in a country where they don't use credit cards asked me to make a reservation for him through booking.com. I wrote his name in the first field, then, I selected "pay for someone else", then I wrote the name of the second guest.

I was surprised that the name of my friend did not show up in the booking confirmation. This booking is not free cancellation, and I contacted the hotel bu did not reply yet.

The room is double and can accommodate three guests.

Is it possible to add a guest without having to pay additional fee ow cancel the whole reservation due to my silly mistake?

Comment: Contact booking.com, call the hotel and ask. You might have to pay for an extra bed. That's all.

Comment: Have you contacted the booking site? (I have seen more often that adding a second guest replaces the name of the first guest but am not sure it is always right.)

Comment: It only shows me the number and email of the property, which are not responding until now. I cannot find where to contact booking.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try the following:

1. Contact the hotel and ask them to amend the reservation. This saves you having to go through booking.com and should work in most cases.
2. Try and [edit the reservation](https://partner.booking.com/en-gb/help/reservations/can-i-make-changes-reservation) using the tools on booking.com
3. [Contact booking.com](https://partner.booking.com/en-gb/help/support-contact/how-do-i-contact-bookingcom) through either the [partner community](https://partner.booking.com/en-gb/community) or using the [inbox feature](https://admin.booking.com/?aid=1190473&page=%2Fhotel%2Fhoteladmin%2Fextranet_ng%2Fmanage%2Finbox.html&utm_source=phc&utm_medium=inbox_link&utm_campaign=213319409&utm_term=inbox&utm_content=en-gb)